# Generate a set of unique numbers java

Tags: java, android, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate unique random numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423523/generate-unique-random-numbers-in-java)

I am creating a lottery app for android which will generate a set of 6 numbers between 1 and 49. The problem I am having is how can I make these numbers unique.

```
Random r = new Random();
int n1=r.nextInt(48) + 1;
ball1.setText(String.valueOf(n1));
int n2=r.nextInt(48) + 1;
ball2.setText(String.valueOf(n2));
int n3=r.nextInt(48) + 1;
ball3.setText(String.valueOf(n3));
int n4=r.nextInt(48) + 1;
ball4.setText(String.valueOf(n4));
int n5=r.nextInt(48) + 1;
ball5.setText(String.valueOf(n5));
int n6=r.nextInt(48) + 1;
ball6.setText(String.valueOf(n6));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very simple solution. You make a for loop which makes new numbers, and if it's the first number you make, you add it to a temporary array. Then every time you generate a new number, you check with your array of already existing numbers, and then if it's not unique, you add 1 to the counter of your for loop.

This will keep going until you have all your unique numbers. Hope that made sense.

Comment: Can be very inefficient if you want to select 99 out of a sequence of 100.

Comment: Well yeah, but I never talked about efficiency in this, so.

Comment: Why did my answer get 2 downvotes? This is a pretty legit way of doing it. If the user wanted an efficient version, I would have worked towards that as well. Jesus christ.

Comment: I can only account for one of them.  Shrugging your shoulders when warned of an inefficient approach - rather than doing something about it (e.g. an edit) is the main reason.

Comment: Even if I edited this, it would still receive a downvote. This site some times :/

Comment: +1 to undo some of this harshness. This approach is plenty fast for this scenario and probably most others. It's worth noting that there's a better solution, but this is the simple and easy solution that first comes to mind. Downvotes are for answers that are wrong. At worst this answer deserves a 0, and because it has educational value  probably a bit more.

Answer (score 6):

This is a classic task. Take the array of [1..49] values, generate 6 random permutations and then take 6 first items of the permuted array.

This is called shuffling ([Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)).

Comment: Excuse me, messed up with the tags. A quick google search with "Knuth shuffle" gives the link on Wikipedia. You got it right, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  Good answer, BTW.