# Issue with randomize method

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, methods, random

I have a method that is not working properly.
The method is supposed to sort a set of numbers from 1 to 20 randomly (each number
must appear just once). 
My issue here is that when I run the program, some numbers are repeated several times.
The code is the following:

```
public static int randomize(int index) {

    //This array will hold the 20 numbers.
    int[] randomIndex = new int[20];

    Random ranNum = new Random();

    for (int x = 0; x<20; x++) {
        int temp;

        //The number is generated randomly and saved in temp.
        temp = ranNum.nextInt(20);

        //This loop skips the first index.
        if (x != 0){

            /*Here, the loop is supposed to compare a generated number with
            the previous one*/
            for (int y = 1; y<=x; y++) {


                while(temp == randomIndex[x-y] ) {

                    /*If the while loop finds that temp variable matches any previous                          
                    number it will generate another random number for it until it finds
                    no matches.*/
                    temp = ranNum.nextInt(20);

                }  
            }
        }

    /*Once no match has been found for temp, the number is assigned to an index, 
    and the loop is executed with a x variable increment.
    randomIndex[x] = temp;

    }
   //Finally the array with the set of random numbers is sent to the main function.
   return randomIndex[index];

  }
```

And I got the following output:

```
19, 19, 5, 16, 6, 2, 18, 1, 15, 1, 5, 19, 11, 4, 18, 0, 5, 18, 10.
```

So now I have no idea what to do. :C

Comment: Could you please add comments about what your code is *supposed* to do? I think this would also help you in debugging!

Comment: Why not use a `List` and the `Collections.shuffle()` method?

Comment: Or at least add each number you already drew to a list and check whether it's a duplicate with List.contains(newNumber)?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283198/non-repeating-random-numbers-inside-array-java/21283246#21283246

Comment: Your major problem is that you only make sure that the number you're working with is in the list one number at a time, which means that you're not actually checking to make sure it's in the whole list..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Random.nextInt()`, there's no guarantee that the numbers generated are unique.
You should generate numbers from 1 to 20 first, then shuffle the numbers. Now the question is changed to "How to shuffle the numbers randomly?"

Perhaps you can refer the implementation of JDK `Collections.shuffle()`.

The algorithm for shuffling the numbers are simple:

1. Pick first element in the array and swap it with a number at random position.
2. Repeat step 1 until the last element.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid it by using something like this:

```
   final Random random = new Random();


    final HashSet<Integer> integers = new HashSet<>();

    while(integers.size() < 20) {
        integers.add(random.nextInt(20));
    }

    System.out.println(integers);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to generate your random numbers by rejection -- that is, by comparing each random number with all previously accepted numbers, and re-generating new ones until you find one that is is different from all of them.

As others have mentioned, it would be far more efficient to generate the numbers from 1 to 20, and shuffle them with a random permutation.  However, if implemented correctly, your approach should work... eventually.

A random shuffle implementation might look something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {  // index goes from 0..19
  randomIndex[i] = i + 1;  // value goes from 1..20
}

for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
  int j = i + ranNum.nextInt(20 - i);  // choose random j from i <= j < 20
  int temp = randomIndex[i];           // swap elements i and j
  randomIndex[i] = randimIndex[j];
  randomIndex[j] = temp;
}
```

---

The are two reasons why your posted code generates duplicates.  First, when you reject a candidate random number and re-generate a new one, you need to compare it against *all* existing numbers, restarting you inner (`y`) loop from the beginning.  Your existing code doesn't do that.

Second, I believe that the `new Random()` constructor generates a different seed each time it is called.  If so, your `randomize()` function is generating a completely different random list each time, and returning the selected index from it.  In any case, it makes more sense to return the entire array, instead.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your function for generate array from 1 to 20:

```
public static int[] randomize() {

    int[] randomIndex = new int[20];

    Random ranNum = new Random();
    boolean isAlreadyIn;
    boolean isZero;
    int x = 0;

    while (x < 20) {
        isAlreadyIn = false;
        isZero = false;
        int temp;
        temp = ranNum.nextInt(21);
        for(int i = 0; i < randomIndex.length; i++){
            if(temp == 0)
                isZero = true;
            if(temp == randomIndex[i])
                isAlreadyIn = true;
        }
        if (!isZero && !isAlreadyIn){
            randomIndex[x] = temp;
            x++;
        }
    }

   return randomIndex;
}
```

hope it will be helpful.