# Get random list from an array?

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

so, my code like that:

```
import java.util.Random;
String[] arr= (vars.get("Types")).split(";");
int idx = new Random().nextInt(arr.length);
String type = (arr[idx]);
vars.put("b_type", type);
```

The array looks like this

```
` arr = {"id":1, "type_1":1},{"id":2, "type_2":2},{"id":3, "type_3":3},{"id":4, "type_4":4},...'
```

Could anyone help? I need to get random arr2 from the array 'arr'.

It could be one element like

```
`arr1 = {id:value, type_1:value}`
```

or some of them, i.e.

```
`arr1 = [{"id":1, "type_1":1},{"id":4, "type_4":4}]`
```

or equivalent arr1 = arr

Comment: You posted the same question few hours ago, and you were told that your question is inappropriate. why don't you explain your question a little bit??

Comment: I've deleted preveous, and create another one

Comment: Still the question is incomplete, I cannot fully understand your question!!

Comment: edited, I need to get random elements from an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need an random integer value indicating the number of elements of array, then produce random elements and insert into new array.

```
//number of elements in result array
int count = new Random().nextInt(arr.length);


ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
    //random index of element that must be added to result
    int index = new Random().nextInt(arr.length);
    result.add(arr[index]);
}
```

just make sure your elements in result array isn't repetitive.

Here's a solution for that:
Insert your array element to an ArrayList so you can edit elements

```
ArrayList<String> myarray = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    myarray.add(arr[i]);
}
```

Then inside the for:

```
for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
    //random index of element that must be added to result
    int index = new Random().nextInt(myarray.length);
    result.add(myarray[index]);
    myarray.remove(index);
}
```

Comment: For the "non repeating" part you can take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000196/java-generating-non-repeating-random-numbers. `shuffle` and then take the first `count` elements.