# Generate random number for concurrent request without duplicate

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter

Am currently running load test with jmeter triggering 300 request per second concurrently. My application need to generate non duplicate random number, but with these many requests it failing. I cant store it in an set ot Map to prevent duplication, as it take some more time for computation.

So far i have tried

1. System.currentTimeMillis();
2. System.nanoTime()
3. ThreadLocalRandom

All these implementation provide duplicate at some point.

Comment: The only way you can generate non duplicates using nanoTime without map is when you synchronize the source.

Comment: There are already several questions (with answers) on SO about non-repeating, random numbers, for example [Java generating non-repeating random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000196/java-generating-non-repeating-random-numbers/16000210) Have you read them? If you have, then I assume they don't help you. Can you explain why?

Comment: @Abra  I have tried some. With concurrent request its failing. If i run 1000 request for first time its working. On second batch i tried to run again a 1000 request its failing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMeter's [__Random](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function.

Go to your Function Helper from the Menu and then select your Random function from the dropdown. You can generate and copy your random function very easily.

Here is an example: `${__Random(000000100,999999999,)}`

For more references you can check: [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Each JMeter thread (virtual user) has its number accessible by [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function. The iteration of the Thread Group can be obtained using [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__threadGroupName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadGroupName) functions combination like:

   ```
   ${__V(__jm__${__threadGroupName}__idx,)}
   ```

   so the construction like:

   ```
   ${__threadNum}${__V(__jm__${__threadGroupName}__idx,)}
   ```

   should provide you unique numbers which will not repeat during single test execution.

   [image]
2. If you need to repeat the test more than once and the approach from point 1 will be "known" to the system - you can pre-generate the unique list of truly random numbers somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) and store it into a CSV file and in the main Thread Group you will be able to refer the generated data using normal [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)