# Generate more than one random numbers using native or built-in function

Tags: java, random, duplicates

I know for generating random number there is random function in java

```
for example 

       int randomNumber = ( int )( Math.random() * 9999 );
```

which will generate randomNumber from [0,9999] but it only returns one number by given range.

But I just want to know **if there is any built in function or you can say native function** which will generate more than one random numbers and it should also not match with each other

suppose from above example if i want to generate 4 number

it will return like 1,10,50,5544

Here you can see that there is a four random number and it is not matching with each other .

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423523/generate-unique-random-numbers-in-java?rq=1) for a possible solution

Comment: please take care of your tags, this here is a basic language question, completely unrelated to swing, java-me, java-ee or android (which I removed)

Comment: As I get Java .. they try to provide only basic functions in the core of the language. Getting N unique results out of the Core Random function can be done in 2-3 rows of simple code .. so no point to implement this as a separate function.

Answer (score 4):

try something like this

Create an `ArrayList` and add your random number and while adding check if `ArrayList` already contains the number or not.

Eg:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (numbers.size()<=YOUR_MAX_SIZE)
{
    int randomInteger = ( int )( Math.random() * 9999 );
    if (!numbers.contains(randomInteger)) {
    {
       numbers.add(randomInteger);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya michal that's i know by that way i can do by different different way but i just want to know if there is built in native function or not!

Comment: I doubt there is any.. I haven't found any such methods.. but if there exists such method that will be very great...

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit - No, there's not. Check the documentation.

Comment: +1 for being the only other answer so far that accounts for 'no duplicates'.

Comment: If you use this solution with a `Set` you can get rid of the `contains` check.

Comment: Thanks Michael for suggestion me i give +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

Another technique (besides the one shown by @MichaelShrestha) is to put the entire range of numbers in a collection, then [shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) it and take the numbers in the shuffled order.

It has the advantage that whereas the other method might spin though many (many) numbers to find a non-duplicate random value, this will only have to be run once.  OTOH, for small collections of numbers, @Michael's technique might be faster.

Comment: Thank you so so so much Andrew :) Will give u +1 points for nice suggestion :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this, as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029495/how-can-i-generate-random-number-in-specific-range-in-android):

```
int min = 1;
int max = 10000;

Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

EDIT:

With no duplicates:

```
Random rng = new Random(); // Ideally just create one instance globally
int min = 1;
int max = 10000;
Set<Integer> generated = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
while (generated.size() < numbersNeeded)
{
    Integer next = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    generated.add(next);
}
```

[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040001/creating-random-numbers-with-no-duplicates)

Comment: No, I was thanking you for showing me that I missed that part :-) The down-vote made me saaad :-D

Comment: Thanks G00dy for suggestion me i give +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not built in api. but you can use something like this

```
public static int[] getRandoms(int amount, int range){
    int[] result = new int[amount];
    ArrayList tempList = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i< range; i++)
       tempList.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(tempList);
    for(int i = 0; i< amount; i++)
       result[i] = (int)tempList.get(i);
    return result;
}
```

Here amount is the number of randome numbers you want and the range is the maximum range of random number

Comment: Ya thanks :) by this way is also useful but there is no any built in native function???

Comment: I haven't found any so far. But if you find any please share with us :)

Comment: *"no any built in native function???"*  'Built in' reads like 'lazy ass' here.  Put it in a method and there is your 'built in' function.  Also note that while one '?' indicates a question, 2 or more typically indicates a bozo.

Comment: Thanks Stine for suggestion me i give +1 :)

Comment: Ok ok Sorry Dear Bro Andrew thanks for your nice suggestion i have to keep in mind this technical terms :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<Integer> rnumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 9999);
        while (rnumbers.contains(randomNumber)) {
            randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 9999);
        }
        rnumbers.add(randomNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As HashSet contains unique object... You can have the unique random numbers.

```
Set uniqueRandomNumber = new HashSet();
 int i = 5 //number Of Random Number Required;
 for(int = 0; i<5; 1++){
    int randomNumber = ( int )( Math.random() * 9999 );
    uniqueRandomNumber.add(randomNumber);
 }
```