# How do we generate a random but unique number in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to generate a random unique number for every Http request hitting my application.

How do make sure the uniqueness of such a number. Does java provide any method or API for this?

Comment: If it's random, it's not guaranteed to be unique. Look for Unique ID solutions, not random ones.

Comment: Take a look at the [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115722/generating-unique-random-numbers-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use java.util.Random - http://java.about.com/od/javautil/a/randomnumbers.htm

Comment: Doesn't really make any attempt to create *unique* numbers, though...

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`java.util.UUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class for that.

```
UUID rand = UUID.randomUUID();
System.out.println(rand);
```