# Non repeating random integers in Java

Tags: java, random, integer

I'm trying to get a simple bit of java code spit out the numbers 1-6 in random order without repeating. I've manage to get it to spit out six random integers between one and six, but it only checks to see if a number is used once. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class kirbyInt

{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6;


        Random rand = new Random();

        num1 = rand.nextInt((6-1) + 1) + 1;
        System.out.println(num1);

        num2 = rand.nextInt((6-1) + 1) + 1;

        if (num2 == num1)
        {
            num2 = rand.nextInt((6-1) + 1) + 1;
            System.out.println(num2);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(num2);
        }

        num3 = rand.nextInt((6-1) + 1) + 1;

        if (num3 == num1 || num3 == num2)
        {
            num3 = rand.nextInt((6-1) + 1) + 1;
            System.out.println(num3);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(num3);
        } 

        num4 = rand.nextInt((6-1) + 1) + 1;

        if (num4 == num1 || num4 == num2 || num4 == num3)
        {
            num4 = rand.nextInt((6-1) + 1) + 1;
            System.out.println(num4);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(num4);
        } 

        num5 = rand.nextInt((6-1) + 1) + 1;
        if (num5 == num1 || num5 == num2 || num5 == num3 || num5 == num4)
        {
            num5 = rand.nextInt((6-1) + 1) + 1;
            System.out.println(num5);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(num5);
        } 

        num6 = rand.nextInt((6-1) + 1) + 1;
        if (num6 == num1 || num6 == num2 || num6 == num3 || num6 == num4 || num6 == num5)
        {
            num6 = rand.nextInt((6-1) + 1) + 1;
            System.out.println(num6);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(num6);
        } 

    }

}
```

Comment: You could use a do-while loop instead of an if, to generate a new number until it matches your condition. However, you really need to look into using an array or set for this.

Comment: Can't you use arrays or something? When you see too much repeated code, you probably can simplify your problem, and that's the case.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8115722/230513).

Answer (score 2):

You could put your numbers in a ArrayList. Then get a random number between 0-5 and print and then remove the number at that position from the ArrayList. That will leave only 5 numbers, get the next random number between 0-4, print and remove the number at that random index, so on and so forth till you only have one and just print that one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to approach this problem. Let's restate exactly what you want to do.

## The Problem

You want to create `n` random numbers where for a given number `k` is not in the previous `k-1` numbers

## The Solution

Create a `Set` for holding random numbers, when you create a new one, add it to the set if and only if it is not already in the `Set`, otherwise generate a new random number and repeat.

## Code Example

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class RandomNum {

    public static final void main(String[] args){
        final Random r = new Random();
        final Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                while(true) {
                int num = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
                if (s.contains(num) == false) {
                    s.add(num);
                    System.out.println(num);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Output

```
/tmp$ javac RandomNum.java
/tmp$ java RandomNum
5
1
3 
2
4
6
```

## Other Options

In principle you could use other data structures to hold the generated random numbers, such as a `List`. A `Set` has the nice advantage of being relatively quick to search in case you want to generate more than 6 values. You could get similar performance with an `ArrayList`. However the use of a `Set` has one more important advantage, it is reflects the semantics of what you intend (an unordered non-repeating set of values). You don't care about the ordering in the collection and you **don't want duplicate values**. A `List` is an ordered collection of values, a `Set` is an unordered set of values (meaning the elements can't be duplicated in the `Set` and they have no relation to each other with respect to the when they were added to the`Set`). When coding it is *almost always* a good idea to choose data structures that don't just **work** but reflect the semantics of **what you mean**.

Answer (score 0):

Small question: Why do you do `rand.nextInt((6-1) + 1)` instead of `rand.nextInt(6)`?

Now, about the task at hand: what I would is start from a list of possible numbers; choose randomly one of the existing indexes in the list (the result being the number at that index); remove the number from the list. When the list is empty, you can no longer take a number.

The nice thing about that solution is that you don't have to re-try several times generating a random number until you find one that hasn't already been used.

Exemple code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        final Random rand = new Random();

        // Fill list
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            integers.add(i);
        }

        // Take numbers in random order
        while (!integers.isEmpty()) {
            final int index;
            if (integers.size() > 1) {
                index = rand.nextInt(integers.size() - 1);
            } else {
                // rand.nextInt(0) would throw an exception rather than return 0
                index = 0;
            }
            final int result = integers.remove(index);
            System.out.println("Result: " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as

```
public class NonRepreatedRandomNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
        Random rd = new Random();
        int num;
        while(true){
            num = rd.nextInt(6) + 1;
            if(myList.size() ==  6)
                break;
            if(!myList.contains(num)){
                myList.add(num);
                System.out.println(myList);
            }else
                continue;
        }
    }
}
```