# Select a random int that doesn't exist

Tags: java

I am doing something where I have to choose a couple random numbers, without choosing the same number again. I have tried many ways, but they will not work. I checked if the random number exists in my int[], and reset the int to another random, but what is that other random also exists, I tried fixing that but I ran into problems.

Here's my current code:

```
p.sendMessage("debug over max");
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i=0;i<max + 1;i++) {
            int ran = r.nextInt(arenaAmount);
            if (ran == 0) ran = 1;
            arenas[i] = ran;
        }
```

Thats what I have so far,
so how can I make sure it doesn't have the same number. If there is another thread already please link me to it.

Thanks, Joey.

Comment: can't you pick the previous random number again? or any of the previous numbers?

Comment: Or set a Random range to exclude (either above or below) the previously chosen random integer?

Comment: [This](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61338/generate-random-numbers-without-repetitions) might be useful.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115722/generating-unique-random-numbers-in-java) might also help.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to add the already generated numbers to a `Set` and generate random numbers until you hit one that isn't already in that `Set`.

But that's probably not a very good solution, check the accepted answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61338/generate-random-numbers-without-repetitions) for a thorough explanation.

As mentioned by [Giovanni Botta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327788/giovanni-botta) in the comments, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8115744/3425536)'s another simple solution that's probably better than the `Set` based one.

Comment: @ColinD True, added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

make a arenas a `Set`

```
Random r = new Random(); 
int ran = r.nextInt(); 
while( ! arenas.add(ran) ) {
   ran = r.nextInt(); 
}
```

add will fail on an attempted re-entry of a value.

Comment: I tried that, still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of integers from `1` to `maxValue`, shuffle it and get the `numElements` first elements:

```
List<Integer> shuffledList(int maxValue, int numElements) {
    if (numElements >= maxValue) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number of elements in the list must be less than maxValue.");
    }
    List<Integer> numbers = range(1, maxValue);
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);
    return numbers.subList(0, numElements);
}

List<Integer> range(int from, int to) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(to - from);
    for (int i = from; i < to; i++) {
        numbers.add(i);
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

This way, you are sure to get different numbers without the Set overhead. Making a call like `shuffledList(10, 5)` would, for example, return a list like `[8, 7, 5, 1, 2]`, with 5 elements, where the smallest possible element is 1 and the greatest possible element is 9.

Also, if you are using Java 8 you can discard the `range` function and do this instead:

```
List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.range(1, maxValue)
                                 .boxed()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```