# Finding same and consecutive numbers in a List

Tags: java, arraylist

been trying to find a way to solve [this CodeWars challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55eeddff3f64c954c2000059/train/java) but can't find a way to check if there are eg. 4 consecutive numbers. If i got 2 i could just do: `if (s.get(i) == s.get(i + 1)`
but how do I actually check if there are maybe 10 consecutive numbers? I cant just do  `s.get(i) == ... == s.get(i + 10)` 
becasue there might be 11, so for sure thats not the answer Im looking for. So far Ive got this, because Im pretty sure I have to iterate through all the objects but have no clue how to do the comparison and addition to my result ArrayList so it replaces those consecutive numbers.

```
public static List<Integer> sumConsecutives(List<Integer> s) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(s);
   for (int i : s) {
       if () // checking if there are consecutive same numbers
   }
}
```

Comment: Keep track of the previous number, and check against that one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Consecutive Numbers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419113/finding-consecutive-numbers-in-java)

Comment: And reset the increment once you changed of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the most straightforward solution I can think of:

```
public static List<Integer> sumConsecutives(List<Integer> s) {
    ArrayList<Integer> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
    int currentRepeating = 0;
    for (int i : s) {
        if (returnList.isEmpty() || currentRepeating != i) {
            currentRepeating = i;
            returnList.add(i);
        } else {
            returnList.set(returnList.size() - 1, returnList.get(returnList.size() - 1) + i);
        }
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

For each number `i` in the input, if the current repeating number is not equal to `i`, add `i` to the return list and set the current repeating number to `i`. If it *is* equal to the current repeating number, add it to the last element in the list.