# Generating half a million unique integers in java

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

I wish to generate 500000 unique random integers within range of 1 to a million. The numbers have to be unique and i want it in **atleast** linear time and without using so much memory. Can someone think of a solution ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115722/generating-unique-random-numbers-in-java

Answer (score 1):

As [was said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115722/generating-unique-random-numbers-in-java) before, you can shuffle the numbers, and pull the first half so they'll be unique. This is linear, since shuffling is `O(n)`, and taking the first part is `O(n/2)`.

Hare is a modified implementation from that thread. This will print 500k unique random numbers from the range 1-1m.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class UniqueRandomNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=1; i<1000001; i++) {
        list.add(new Integer(i)); // adding all the numbers between 1-1m to a list.
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list); // using the built in shuffle function to make the unique order
    for (int i=0; i<500000; i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i)); // printing the first 500k. Replace this with whatever you want to do with those numbers. 
        //Notice - since it might take a while, it might be worth it to let the user know of the progress.
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If memory is at a premium, use a bitmap to remember which of the million have been chosen, then repeatedly choose a random number and stop after 500,000. This is basically storage optimal, since lg(1e6 choose 0.5e6) is not much less than 1e6.