# Generate a unique random number for each array value

Tags: java, random

I have this method that generates a number (1-10) for each array value listed in this method. I want the whole set of numbers to be displayed as a set of unique numbers. How to do this?

```
public static int generateNumbers(int[] lotteryNumbers) {

    Random randNum = new Random();

    lotteryNumbers[0] = randNum.nextInt(10);
    lotteryNumbers[1] = randNum.nextInt(10);
    lotteryNumbers[2] = randNum.nextInt(10);
    lotteryNumbers[3] = randNum.nextInt(10);
    lotteryNumbers[4] = randNum.nextInt(10);

    return lotteryNumbers[4];
}
```

Comment: You should not use random.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115722/generating-unique-random-numbers-in-java

Comment: @nikpon what's wrong with `Random` ? It's perfectly fine

Comment: @Dici I didn't get what you asking. If you have a question, ask it in the section of questions.

Comment: @nikpon you told him not to use `Random`, but there is nothing wrong with this class

Comment: @Dici I don't understand what do you say. yes, nothing wrong with it, but the code is wrong.

Comment: @nipkon Just look at what you told him : *You should not use random*. Nevermind...

Comment: @dici yes, He thought that using random he can generate a set of unique numbers. But it's wrong.

Comment: By number 1-10, you mean 1 and 10 are both included? In that case, use 1+nextInt(10), because your code nextInt(10) would return range of 0-9 only.

Answer (score 5):

An easy solution is to generate a list of the 10 digits, shuffle that list and get the first five elements:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(list);
Integer[] lotteryNumbers = list.subList(0, 5).toArray(new Integer[10]);
```

[`Collections.shuffle(list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) is an utility method that randomly permutes the given list in place.

If you are using Java 8, this can be written as:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(list);
int[] loterryNumbers = list.subList(0, 5).stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

Comment: Thank @Tunkai. But is there a way how I can generate unique numbers using Random? cause I'm only allowed to use random since it's a school assignment.

Comment: There is no built-in way. What you can do is generate an int using Random in a loop until the number you have obtained has not been found before.

Comment: @N.Cre see my answer, it is basically the same algorithm as `Collections.shuffle` but without using a library method. It is good to know and also good for your assignment, but keep in mind in real-life Tunaki answer is better. I would not mind if you upvoted mine though :D

Answer (score 3):

A naive technique is to pick randomly in the set you want to "shuffle" :

```
public static int[] generateNumbers(int exclusiveMaxValue) {
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(exclusiveMaxValue);
    for (int i=0 ; i<values.size() ; i++) values.add(i);

    int[] result = new int[exclusiveMaxValue];
    Random rd = new Random();
    for (int i=0 ; i<result.length ; i++) {
       result[i] = values.remove(rd.nextInt(values.size()));
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, `List.remove` is usually `O(n)`, so the whole method is quadratic, which is very expensive. You can perform a shuffle in `O(n)` by simply swapping elements in place (that is what `Collections.shuffle` does) :

```
public static int[] generateNumbers(int exclusiveMaxValue) {
    int[] result = new int[exclusiveMaxValue];
    for (int i=0 ; i<result.length ; i++) result[i] = i;

    Random rd = new Random();
    for (int i=result.length - 1 ; i>=0 ; i--) {
       swap(result, i, rd.nextInt(i + 1));
    }
    return result;
}

private static swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method generates the sequence of length N of unique numbers in range [0, N -1].

```
public static int[] generateNumbers(int length) {
    final int[] array = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
    shuffle(array);
    return array;
}
```

For shuffling Fisher–Yates algorithm was used:

```
public static void shuffle(final int[] array) {
    final Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        final int randomIdx = random.nextInt(i + 1);
        final int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[randomIdx];
        array[randomIdx] = temp;
    }
}
```

- Thanks of ([Ronald Fisher and Frank Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)) the algorithm's time complexity is O(n)
- This implementation works on arrays (with primitives) not on collections (with instances of Integer class that wraps a value of the primitive type int in an object) - it matters if array size is big enough

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way which uses a set and fills it until it grows to the size required. It generates **numbersToDraw** distinct random numbers in range from **min** to **max** (inclusive). It also preserves the order in which numbers were drawn (that is what *LinkedHashSet* is for).

```
private static Set<Integer> drawNumbers(int min, int max, int numbersToDraw) {
    if (max < min) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Minimum must be less than maximum.");
    }
    if (max < 0 || min < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Both range numbers must be positive.");
    }
    final int countOfNumbers = max - min + 1;
    if (countOfNumbers < numbersToDraw) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Range is not big enough.");
    }
    final Random randomizer = new SecureRandom();
    final Set<Integer> numbersDrawn = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    while (numbersDrawn.size() < numbersToDraw) {
        final int randomNumber = min + randomizer.nextInt(countOfNumbers);
        numbersDrawn.add(randomNumber);
    }
    return numbersDrawn;
}
```

If you do not require numbers to be unique, you can use this in Java 8:

```
final Random randomizer = new SecureRandom();

final List<Integer> numbersDrawn = IntStream
        .range(0, numbersToDraw)
        .mapToObj(i -> min + randomizer.nextInt(max - min + 1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you do not require numbers to be unique, BUT you want to print their distinct values (is that your original question?):

```
final Random randomizer = new SecureRandom();

final Set<Integer> numbersDrawn = IntStream
        .range(0, numbersToDraw)
        .mapToObj(i -> min + randomizer.nextInt(max - min + 1))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

And one more alternative for your concrete case:

```
final Set<Integer> distinctNumbers = Arrays
  .stream(lotteryNumbers)
  .distinct() // you can leave this as the set is distinct automatically
  .boxed()
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```