# Java8 code not resolving in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I am using JDK - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60

However, ([on an earlier question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640867/generate-random-number-array-and-replace-duplicates)) a SO user gave me a Java8 solution to my problem:

```
int[] luckyArray = new Random().int(1, 59).distinct().limit(6).toArray();
```

I copied the code into my Main class and it is not resolving. Any idea why?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the problem of IntelliJ IDEA, but your code.

```
int[] luckArray = new Random().ints(1, 59).distinct().limit(6).toArray();
```

See it, **ints** not int.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mistype in your code. The red underline means that you have a syntax error. A good way to get rid of those is to hover your mouse over the error to get an explanation, then put the blinking cursor on it press `alt + enter` in IntelliJ IDEA to get a list of suggestions to fix the issue. If you suspect that you don't have the correct method typed, selecting the whole method (`int`)  in your case and pressing `ctrl + space` will show a list of methods that you can use on that object. As you type, you will get more specific suggestions.