# Math.random repeating itself

Tags: java, math, random

My code so far is working almost to how it should be working. The instructions are above the method. The only problem that I'm encountering is that `Math.random();` repeats itself when called multiple times. I wanted to know if there was a solution to prevent the `Math.random();` from repeating itself;

```
/**
 * Apply an "efficient selection shuffle" to the argument.
 * The selection shuffle algorithm conceptually maintains two sequences
 * of cards: the selected cards (initially empty) and the not-yet-selected
 * cards (initially the entire deck). It repeatedly does the following until
 * all cards have been selected: randomly remove a card from those not yet
 * selected and add it to the selected cards.
 * An efficient version of this algorithm makes use of arrays to avoid
 * searching for an as-yet-unselected card.
 * @param values is an array of integers simulating cards to be shuffled.   
 */
public static void selectionShuffle(int[] values) {
    ArrayList<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int size=52;
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
        /*int random=(int)(Math.random()*51);
        temp.add(random);
        values[j]=temp.get(j);*/
        int random=(int)(Math.random()*51);
        temp.add(values[random]);
        values[j]=temp.get(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Math.random()` will run 52 times since you have placed it in the loop. It will run everytime you call the method. Is that your issue?

Comment: Or do you mean the value returned by `Math.random()` ?

Comment: I suggest you try to implement the comment above your method. Your current code doesn't do that. (I'd also suggest using the `Random` class instead of `Math.random`.)

Comment: You could use create  `Random random = new Random();` outside of the loop, and then call `random.nextDouble()` inside.

Comment: Tbh you should rather use the `Math.random` to **swap** random elements. Not to pick a random one and put it in the temp array, because then you'll surely have some duplicates...

Comment: Given a completely random distribution in the range [0..50] it is quite likely that you'll get duplicates.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115722/generating-unique-random-numbers-in-java

Comment: @Enigo that is not a problem, `randomGenerator` is defined as static in `Math`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array/1520212#1520212 for a *real* implementation of the algorithm described.

Comment: My code is supposed to run 52 times its supposed to shuffle a deck of cards. The code is supposed to take a random index out of values[] and put it in temp and then back into values[] shuffled.

Comment: @TariqAl-Attrash Try `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(values));`

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is how can I store the number generated from the Math.random() temporarily, and then test it against the next number produced by the Math.random()

Comment: We're not allowed to use Collections.shuffle(); :D

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera, that won't work since `values` is a primitive array. If you have Guava, you could do `Collections.shuffle(Ints.asList(values))`.

Comment: Please check my solution to ensure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the integers 0-51 in a random order without repeats:

- Add those numbers to a list, in order
- Call `Collections.shuffle` on that list

Simply using `(int) (52 * Math.random())` 51 times will almost guarantee that some numbers will be repeated (and, of course, some will be missing), according to the [birthday paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you believe that Math.random is "repeating" because you always choose a new number between 0 and 51 to add to your `values` array. And you are overwriting the early part of the `values` array before you might have the chance to select those numbers.

Think about the process as outlined in the instructions. If you're selecting from the initial array once per iteration, and moving those selections into the new `temp` array, then shouldn't `values` be getting smaller every time? Maybe you don't always want a random number from 0-51.

And ignore everyone who is telling you different ways to do the shuffle. Obviously you're trying to implement the algorithm as given for coding practice.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your issue is but try to use java.util.Random instead.

```
public static void selectionShuffle(int[] values)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    int size=52;

    for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
        // If you wan to generate a random number up to a maximum value,
        // use randomGenerator.nextInt(maximum) instead
        int random = randomGenerator.nextInt() * 51;
        temp.add(values[random]);
        values[j]=temp.get(j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When numbers are random, every number has an equal chance of occurring, not matter what has occurred previously.  This means random number must be able to repeat themselves or they no longer truly random.

If you want a set of numbers, cards, songs to appear in a random order without repeating, this is called a shuffle. Note: the last number, card, or song won't be random at all because it will be the only one left.

With a random sequence you can even get the same number appearing many times.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/randomly-no-so-random.html

```
Random random = new Random(441287210);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.print(random.nextInt(10)+" ");
```

prints

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

and

```
Random random = new Random(-6732303926L);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.print(random.nextInt(10)+" ");
```

prints

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you don't want `Math.random()` to return a number more than once. If that's the issue, what we are going to do is allow `Math.random()` to return whatever it likes but we will use only the non-repeated numbers.

Try this:

```
public static void selectionShuffle(int[] values) {
    ArrayList<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int size=52;
    Integer a[]=new Integer[size];
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
        int random=(int)(Math.random()*51);
        if(a.[random]==null) //to ensure that only unique nos. are used.
        {
        temp.add(values[random]);
        values[j]=temp.get(j);
        a.[random]=1;
        // the above code will only be executed if `a[random]` is null
        //ensures that this executes only when unique number is generated
    }
    else
    {
      j--; 
    //so that 52 iterations occur successfully. We don't want any iteration to go waste.
    }
 }
```

I have used an `Integer` array to ensure that unique numbers are used. Each time unique number is generated, we are assigning `1` or some other integer to that particular index of the Integer array. Your dependent code will only be executed if the `a[]'s` value is not set at the index corresponding to the generated integer number that is `random` .

Comment: What exactly do you intend when you write `a.[random]=""`?

Comment: @AndyTurner I missed one '=' sign. Thanks for pointing it out. And I changed `int a[]` to `Integer a[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a random draw without replacement but you have implemented a random draw with replacement...

Put the cards in an array of size 52 then in your first draw do something like:

```
(int)(Math.random()*51 + 1);
```

Which gives you a random number between 1-52, say you get 4, then update the array by removing the 4th element leaving you with an array of size 51. Then make your second draw:

```
(int)(Math.random()*50 + 1);
```

And so on...