# Java: Filling an array with random numbers without duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm trying to fill an array with random numbers. There must be unique.
I've tried this:

```
int random(int[] arr) {
    int number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        Random rn = new Random();
        number = rn.nextInt(100);
        for (int j = i; j>0; j--) {
            if(arr[j]==zahl){
                random(arr);
            }
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

I would be thankfull if you could help with my problem.

Comment: Fill the array with the values you want, then shuffle as described in the linked post.

Comment: To ensure distinct values, fill a `Set` which automatically eliminates duplicates. Then feed that `Set` to constructor of a `List`.

Comment: @JimGarrison - _"...with the values you want,"_ OP doesn't know the values, they are _random_. It it not a random _order_ that's wanted, as `shuffle` would do, it is random _contents_ that OP is after.  Basil's comment to use a `Set` would do well for that.

Comment: This question is already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115722/generating-unique-random-numbers-in-java