# How to create a function that returns unique random numbers?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have tried some solutions from the forum but did not worked for me, if the answer be specific in kotlin language then it will me more helpful for me.

Comment: yes there are, but I did not found them helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this out with recursion function that will only return unique random number in the range of 0 to 6.

```
private var randomNumber: Int = 0
private var integerList: MutableList<Int>? = null

private fun getRandomNumber(): Int {
    val rand = Random()
    randomNumber = rand.nextInt(7)
    if (integerList!!.contains(randomNumber)) {
        getRandomNumber()
    } else {
        integerList!!.add(randomNumber)
    }
    return randomNumber
}
```

Comment: what is integer list in this example? why not use a map for more efficient lookups?

Comment: see the edited code, integerList is a mutable list that will contain the generated random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Thompson say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115722/generating-unique-random-numbers-in-java) you can

- Add each number in the range sequentially in a list
- Shuffle it
- Take the first 'n' numbers from the list

A simple implementation would be:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class UniqueRandomNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=1; i<11; i++) {
            list.add(new Integer(i));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

This would print 3 unique random numbers from 1 to 10

Comment: This could get unwieldy if the user requires integers from 1 - million.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] Numbers;
int num = 0;

getRandomNum();

public void getRandomNum()
{
   Random rand = new Random(10);
   if(Numbers.contains(rand))
   {
      Log.i("console","Try Again");
   }
   else
   {
      num = rand;
      Numbers.add(rand); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Numbers should be a List.

Comment: In order to improve the quality of your answer, please add some commentary about what this code does and how it solves the original question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I wouldn't recommend a function for that, rather use a class that encapsulates the logic which increases usability.

**1st option**

You can use the `List` function (yes, it's really a function here) to generate a list of all possible numbers, then shuffle it and after that iterate over it.

```
class UniqueRandomNumbers(lowerBound: Int, upperBound: Int) {
    private val iterator = List(upperBound - lowerBound) { 
        lowerBound + it + 1
    }.shuffled().iterator()
    val next get() = if (iterator.hasNext()) iterator.next() else null
}
```

**2nd option**

Alternatively you could generate random numbers until you find one that has not been consumed before.

```
class UniqueRandomNumbers(val lowerBound: Int, val upperBound: Int) {
    private val consumedNumbers = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    val next: Int?
        get() {
            var newNumber: Int

            if (consumedNumbers.size == (upperBound - lowerBound + 1)) {
                return null
            }

            do {
                newNumber = Random.nextInt(lowerBound, upperBound + 1)
            } while (newNumber in consumedNumbers)

            consumedNumbers += newNumber

            return newNumber
        }
}
```

Usage in both cases:

```
val numberProvider = UniqueRandomNumbers(0, 2)

// returns 0, 1, 2 or null if all numbers have been consumed
numberProvider.next
```