# Unique Random Number Creation in java

Tags: java

I am creating 10 digit random unique numbers in java am able to create but Numbers are repeating after some numbers, i want to create unique numbers which should not be repeated even server restart also, i want solution like **UUID.randomUUID()** for 10 digit number.

Am using below Code

```
(long) Math.floor(Math.random() * 9_000_000_000L) + 1_000_000_000L
```

This code is not producing unique 10 digit numbers.

Comment: How often do you need a number?

Comment: Then generate again until you get a unique number, that's the only way.

Comment: If it has to be unique, it can't be random... Random numbers can randomly repeat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating Unique Random Numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115722/generating-unique-random-numbers-in-java)

Comment: Is there any way using current timestamp

Comment: That's why I wrote my first comment, to which you haven't replied. It's not answerable without that clarification.

Comment: It is not repeated in constant count, sometimes after 70000, sometimes after 40000 numbers

Answer (score -1):

Given that there are a finite number (10^10) 10 digit numbers, you cannot do this indefinitely, as eventually you will run out of new unique numbers.

The Apache Commons Lang library has a method `RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(int count)` which, as the name suggests, produces a `String` of a given length containing random digits, which can then be mapped to a `long` using `Long.parseLong()`.

Using this, you can generate random values. You must then store these values (probably in some kind of database, depending on your deployment situation), and verify that any new values have not been used before.

Note that this method will not check for leading zeroes, so if that is important to you, you must do that as well.

Also note, the longer you go without repeating values, the more predictable (and therefore less random) the values become. If you are using this for cryptographic/security conscious purposes, you **must** use a cryptographically secure random number generator (look into `SecureRandom` in the JDK).