# math question about random (x) and random() % x - Java

Tags: java, math

so my question is at Java but it can be in any programming language.
there is this declaration :

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

We want to get a random number at range 0 to x

I want to know if there is any mathematical difference between the following:

```
rnd.nextInt() % x;
```

and

```
rnd.nextInt(x)
```

The main question is, are one of these solutions more *random* than the other? Is one solution more appropriate or "correct" than the other? If they are equal I will be happy to see the mathematics proof for it

Comment: What do you mean by "is it more options"? Using `%` has worse statistical properties.

Comment: My lecturer claims that using the modulo has more options that are not damaged in the same number twice if we want a number from 0 to 100 for example.
I claimed it wasn't true and I'm looking for a way to prove it. Or I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry for my English, what I'm trying to say is let's say we want to fill an array of 10 with random numbers from 0 to 100. I want to use and.nextInt(100), but my teacher said that using rnd.nextInt() % 100 will give us more random numbers and the chance to get the same number twice reduced, I said it's wrong but I don't know how to explain it, I want to know if I'm right or not and what the math way to proof it

Comment: To help illustrate the problem, let's use a smaller number space, e.g. let us pretend that `nextInt()` is actually returning `byte` value. In that case, `nextInt()` (no arg) returns a number in range `-128` to `127`, so if `x = 100`, `nextInt() % x` will return `-99` to `99`, and the numbers between `-28` and `27` are twice as likely as the rest. In comparison, `nextInt(x)` will return `0` to `99`, and all the numbers are equally likely. *Conclusion:* You teacher is dead wrong, the chance to get the same number twice is *increased* when using `%`, and the numbers aren't even in the same range.

Comment: Why was this closed? The question may not be perfect, but there's enough to go off of to write an answer. I second Andreas' conclusion that the teacher is dead wrong: short of a random number generator with a _uniform probability distribution_, you'll have a very hard time proving it doesn't cause the issue to compound. Not to mention if `N % n > 0`, then any `a` in `N` would more likely be towards the lower end of `a % n`

Comment: ``rnd = new Random(x);`` creates a new random number generator object. ``rnd.nextInt() % x;`` uses this random number generator. I would not use the % (remainder) operator, but rather use rnd.nextInt(x).

Comment: Fun fact, `% x` is uniformly distributed if its a power of two. The implementation of `nextInt(int bound)` uses this fact. Additionally, it will actually just call `nextInt()` (simplified) in a loop until the outcome is not part of the last integer sequence (which would result in non uniform) and then basically just apply `% x` to it. So the actual implementation is very close to `% x`, just makes sure that its uniformly distributed.

Comment: `rnd = new Random(x)` is in no way equivalent to `rnd.nextInt() % x`. It is unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to "mathematical insight" with "MS Paint".

So, from a statistical standpoint, it would depend on the *distribution* of the numbers being generated. First of all, we'll treat the probability of any one number coming up as an independant event (aka discarding the seed, which RNG, etc). Following that, a modulus simply takes a range of numbers (e.g. `a` from `N`, where `0`<=`a`<`N`), and subdivides them based on the divisor (the `x` in `a % x`). While the numbers are technically from a discrete population (integers), the range of integers for a [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) would be so large that it'd end up looking like a continuous graph anyhow. So let's consider a graph of the [probability distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20a%20probability,that%20the%20value%20of%20the) for a range of numbers:

[image: Example Distributions]

If your random number generator doesn't generate with a uniform distribution across the range of numbers (aka, any number is as likely to come up as another number), then modulo would (potentially) be breaking up the results of a non-uniform distribution. When you consider the individual integers in those ranges as discrete (and individual) outcomes, the probability of any number `i` (0 <= i < x) being the result is the multiplication of the individual probabilities (`i_1` * `i_2` * ... * `i_(N/x)`). To think of it another way, if we overlaid the subdivisions of the ranges, it's plain to see that in non-symmetric distributions, it's much more likely that a modulo would not result in equally likely outcomes:

[image]

Remember, the likelihood of an outcome `i` in the graph above would be achieved through multiplying the likelihood of the individuals numbers (`i_1`, ..., `i_(N/x)`) in the range `N` that could result in `i`. For further clarity, if your range `N` doesn't evenly divide by the modular divisor `x`, there will always be some amount of numbers `N % x` that will have 1 additional integer that could produce their result. This means that most modulus divisors that aren't a power of `2` (and similarly, ranges that are not a multiple of their divisor) could be skewed towards their lower results, regardless of having a uniform distribution:

[image]

So to summarize the point, `Random#nextInt(int bound)` takes all of these things (and more!) into consideration, and will consistently produce an outcome with uniform probability across the range of `bound`. `Random#nextInt() % bound` is only a halfway step that works in some specific scenarios. To your teacher's point, I would argue it's *more* likely you'll see some specific subset of numbers when using the modulus approach, not less.

Answer (score 3):

`new Random(x)` just creates the `Random` object with the given seed, it does not ifself yield a random value.

I presume you are asking what the difference is between `nextInt() % x` and `nextInt(x)`.

The difference is as follows.

#### `nextInt(x)`

`nextInt(x)` yields a random number *n* where *0 ≤ n < x*, evenly distributed.

#### `nextInt() % x`

`nextInt() % x` yields a random number in the full integer range<sup>1</sup>, and then applies modulo *x*. The full integer range includes negative numbers, so the result could also be a negative number. With other words, the range is *−x < n < x*.

Furthermore, the distribution is not even in by far the most cases. `nextInt()` has 2<sup>32</sup> possibilities, but, for simplicity's sake, let's assume it has 2<sup>4</sup> = 16 possibilities, and we choose *x* not to be 16 or greater. Let's assume that *x* is 10.

All possibilities are *0, 1, 2, …, 14, 15, 16*. After applying the modulo 10, the results are *0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5*. **That means that some numbers have a greater likelihood to occur than others.** That also means that the change of some numbers occurring twice has increased.

As we see, `nextInt() % x` has two problems:

1. Range is not as required.
2. Uneven distribution.

So you should definetely use **`nextInt(int bound)`** here. If the requirement is get only unique numbers, you must exclude the numbers already drawn from the number generator. See also [Generating Unique Random Numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115722/generating-unique-random-numbers-in-java).

---

<sup>1</sup> According to [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--).