# Is there any method which generate random numbers with complexity O(1)

Tags: java, random, complexity-theory

I am looking for one efficent way to generate random numbers using java . I want it to be fast and highly secured. Unfortunately SecureRandom class in java and its method nextBytes() generate highly secured random numbers but this method takes me quite time . I am looking if there is any implementation of a method with the same aim as the one above which has complexity O(1) or worst case O(n).

Comment: For background, could you describe what the application of these random numbers will be?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523492/choosing-random-numbers-efficiently

Comment: What do you mean by O(n) in this context? Is n the number of digits?

Comment: @FrankPuffer yes is the number of bytes the file has

Comment: @ENIOMARKU: But then it's pretty obvious that this can never be faster than O(n).

Answer (score 4):

Any RNG or PRNG is going to be `O(N)` or worse<sup>1</sup> to generate N random bits / bytes / whatever.  (It is an `O(N)` operation to copy N bytes / bits ...)

What I think you are really asking is if there are any RNGs or PRNGs that generated numbers fast and / or seed themselves fast.  See this Q & A:

- [How to solve performance problem with Java SecureRandom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137212/how-to-solve-performance-problem-with-java-securerandom)

---

<sup>1 - Actually, a typical crypto-quality PRNG is `O(N)`.  For example, Oracle's `SecureRandom` uses SHA1 by default, and SHA1 is an `O(M)` algorithm when hashing an `M` byte message.  This leads to an `O(N)` PRNG when generating `N` bytes.  Of course, the constant of proportionality for SHA-1 is rather large ... but that is not relevant to the big-O complexity class of the algorithm.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache commons-math3 to generate random numbers.
It has got lots of useful methods for this.
See interface "RandomGenerator" and its implementing classes.